# How to add classes to form fields dynamically created by Django?

Tags: django

I have figured out how to add classes to form fields.  I have the following:

```
# models.py
class Contact(AddressMixin, PhoneMixin):
    contact_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50, blank=False)
    company = models.CharField(_('company'), max_length=50, blank=True)
    photo = models.CharField(_('photo'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(_('notes'), blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

# forms.py
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name', 'company', 'photo', 'notes']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'company': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'photo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'notes': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

The magic is in the `class Meta`, specifically the `widgets` field.  That is where you can define what class to go on what field.  However, for each contact I want to ability to add 1 or more phone numbers so I have the following:

```
# models.py
class Phone(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey('PhoneMixin', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.CharField(_('number'), max_length=50, blank=True)

class PhoneMixin(models.Model):
    phone_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pass

# forms.py
class PhoneForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        exclude = ['entity']
        widgets = {
            'number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Then I have a formset which I believe is the root of the problem:

```
PhoneFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Contact,
    Phone,
    form=PhoneForm,
    exclude=('entity',),
    extra=1
)
```

I may be mistaken but I believe it is the formset that is adding a delete field.  This delete field ends up as a checkbox in my form.  When I inspect the html for this field it has the name `DELETE` so I thought it would be as easy as adding a class to the `DELETE` field in the `Phone` form:

```
# forms.py
class PhoneForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        exclude = ['entity']
        widgets = {
            'number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'DELETE': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'custom-control-input'}),

        }
```

However, that doesn't seem to do it.  I even tried it in all lower case, `delete`, but still no luck.  I suspect the reason is that Django is adding the `DELETE` field *after* my form is evaluated but that is just a guess.  So my question is:

How can I add a class to the `DELETE` field that Django has dynamically added to the `Phone` form?

Answer (score 0):

You can add class for delete checkbox in script. Please refer this one.

```
<table class="table">

        {{ phone_form.management_form }}

        {% for form in phone_form.forms %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                        <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                </thead>
            {% endif %}
            <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} phone_form_formset_row">
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <td>
                        {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                {{ hidden }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                        {{ field }}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'formset/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.phone_form_formset_row').formset({
            addText: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add Contact</button>',
            deleteText: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">remove</button>',
            prefix: 'phone_set'
        });

</script>
```

Comment: I know how to create the template, but nothing you've posted here helps me get a class on the delete field :(